# Decode HTML entities into plain text

Tags: vba, string, ascii

I have a string that includes [HTML entities](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) (e.g. `&plusmn;` - the plus minus symbol).

How can I get the string with those HTML entities decoded into plain text?

Examples:

```
 Input          |  Output
----------------+-------------
&plusmn;        |    ±
Ben &amp; Jerry | Ben&Jerry
```

Comment: Use a dictionary? In any event, the question is very unclear. Please clarify.

Comment: "Use a dictionary?" I dont know, what you mean with that. I have a string, e.g. `strText = "Ben &amp; Jerry"` and I want to get `strText = "Ben&Jerry"`. But metion, that it is only an example. I have up to 10k words in this string and there are more Entity names than `&amp;` in it. You can see all possible Entity names in the list, I gave you the URL.So, my question is, how to convert the string - coming back to my example - from `strText = "Ben &amp; Jerry"` to `strText = "Ben&Jerry"`. Did I miss explaining something?

Comment: I reformulated your question in what I think is the essence. Please check if this corresponds to your expectations. NB: this has nothing to do with ASCII.

Comment: A dictionary (which comes from VBScript but can be created using `CreateObject()` in VBA) is the natural data structure for key-value mappings, which is what you were implicitly asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an `HTMLDocument` object, store the HTML in it, and get the text version of it out of it:

```
Function HtmlDecode(str)
    Dim dom

    Set dom = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    dom.Open
    dom.Write str
    dom.Close
    HtmlDecode = dom.body.innerText
End Function

decoded = HtmlDecode("&plusmn;")   ' =  "±"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a opportunity to "convert" it without creating a new File?

Comment: What do you mean with new file? There is no file created here. Don't be confused by the names of the object or the names of the methods. The created object lives in memory. It is an instance of the `HTMLDocument` class. There is no file involved (despite the misleading name "htmlfile").

Comment: Ah, okay. I was confused because there stood "htmlfile" in the brackets. Thanks, that is, what I searched for.

Comment: That function works great but if you have a lot of data to process the createObject is a huge overhead.  I got a data table in html from an oracle extract that is 450MB.  By setting the "Dim doc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument '*" once in my main function and then calling " doc.body.innerHTML = str : str = doc.body.innerText " as needed (when a & is detected in a field) I cut my processing time from 217 seconds to 7 seconds; instead of calling the HtmlDecode function every time.  '* requires a reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library.